# Why the duration of build process of Cloud Build for ASP.NET Core & Angular is so long?

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-build, build-triggers

An ASP.NET Core API project with Angular can be built in less than one minute in the local machine, but when I use Build Trigger of Google Cloud Builder to automatize the process it takes forever. I am setting the cloudbuild.yaml as following. The project uses .NET Core 2.2 and Angular. What can I do to make Cloud Build run well again?

I have tried to modify CloudBuild.yaml file, like increasing timeout, that did not help either.

This is the cloudbuild.yaml used to deploy the application to AppEngine Flexible. It first installs the dependencies of Angular, then builds it, publish API and deploy the application.

```
steps:
# run npm install for Angular
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
  dir: 'PPlus.Web/ClientApp'
# build Angular for production
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'build','--','--prod']
  dir: 'PPlus.Web/ClientApp'
# publish asp.net core solution  
- name: microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk
  args: ['dotnet', 'publish','-c','Release']
# deploy the webapi to the AppEngine
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['app', 'deploy', 
'./PPlus.Web/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/app.yaml','--version','staging']
timeout: 1800s
```

Since it takes a few seconds to build it in local, it should not take more than a few minutes with Cloud Builder.

The logs of Cloud Build only shows a message indicating Time Out, but the more I increase the timeout limit, the more it takes time without completing.

Comment: Two things off the top of my head: 1) Locally, you likely already have an npm cache. If you're using a hosted agent, it will be clean and will need to actually download all this stuff every time. 2) When pushing your new code, you should avoid pushing the `node_modules` directory. All your necessary code should have been built by this point, so you don't need it. If you include `node_modules` it will take a *very* long time to push all that data to your deployment target.

Comment: Hi Chris, 
Thanks for the comment but as it can be seen from the report of GCP, the timout occurs in the ng build --prod step. I have uploaded the screenhot here:
[link](https://i.imgur.com/JabSAeX.png) 

And from the log files, we see that it times out on the process of webpack: 92% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin

The last time it took 35 minutes and timed out.

Comment: @MehmetOz did you find a solution yet?

Comment: no @Ishmeet, at the time I left the issue to a colleague and I do not think they found a solution. Do you face the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the time you need to resolve the NPM dependencies, first of all include in your `package.json` under `dependencies` only the dependencies required for your build and leave the rest under `devDependencies`.

Secondly, if the enviroment you deploy the project is the same with your dev enviroment, generate and include in your repo the `package-lock.json`.

Now you can run `npm ci --only=prod` instead of `npm install`.

This will skip calculating and fetching the dependencies and start fetching the ones you need right away.

It reduces the NPM module dependencies resolvement dramatically.

Now about the prod. build issue. Sometimes the Node process doesn't allocate enough resources, the process freezes and it doesn't provide feedback.

Try running this instead of `npm run build --prod`

`node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod`

Hope it helps!